# How to publish an Android library as a Maven artifact on Bitbucket?

Tags: android, maven, gradle

I'm trying to publish an Android library as a Maven artifact on a Bitbucket repository, starting from [this article](https://medium.com/@Mul0w/publish-with-gradle-on-bitbucket-1463236dc460?mc_cid=5e6ec8b400&mc_eid=603dfed976#.2mzcozpmd) that was linked in an Android Weekly newsletter issue some time ago. The article describes how to perform publication and how to link the published artifact from another Android project. However, I have not even managed to make the publishing part to correctly work.

Currently, this is the relevant content of the `build.gradle` file belonging to the library project:

```
apply plugin: 'maven'

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://raw.github.com/synergian/wagon-git/releases"
        }
    }
}

configurations {
    deployerJar
}

dependencies {
    deployerJar 'ar.com.synergian:wagon-git:0.2.5'
}
```

The relevant parts of the `build.gradle` file of the library module in the project are as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'maven'

uploadArchives {
    configuration = rootProject.configurations.archives
    repositories {
        configuration = rootProject.configurations.deployerJar
        mavenDeployer {
            pom.groupId = 'com.example'
            pom.artifactId = 'example-library'
            pom.version = '1.0.0'
            repository(url: "${bitbucketUrl}") {
                authentication(userName: bitbucketUsername, password: bitbucketPassword)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

where `bitbucketUrl`, `bitbucketUsername` and `bitbucketPassword` are included in the `gradle.properties` file at the root of the project.

So, what's the problem? When I run the `uploadArchives` task from Android Studio, Gradle shows that the operation has been performed successfully. But nothing appears on the Bitbucket repository.

Nothing is also written about the structure of that repository, except on Wagon Git's website (calling it *documentation* seems a little bit of a stretch to me) where, given repository URL of the form

```
git:releases://git@github.com:synergian/wagon-git.git
```

it is said that `releases` represent a branch of the repository. I obliged that part about the structure, even tried to add a `repository` directory (to mimick the local Maven repository on my machine) but with no luck, and, above all, no clue.

An even more severe issue is that, while I was experimentating with different configurations, I noticed I had the repository URL wrong; however, never, ever, during execution, Gradle noticed the error, and warned or informed me with a suitable message. This lead me to suspect that it wasn't even preparing the artifact to upload, nor trying to connect to Bitbucket, but I was not able to find any pointer as to understand why.

Finally, an even more strange thing happens: when I comment out the line:

```
configuration = rootProject.configurations.deployerJar
```

in the module `build.gradle` file and I run the `uploadArchives` task, Gradle stops with an error saying that it is unable to find a proper wagon to manage the git protocol, which is expected; however, in the process, the Maven artifact appears in the local repository on my machine. So, by making the publishing process crash, at least I am able to work locally with my library from other projects depending on it, through Gradle management of Maven-like dependencies.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but I found the newer [`maven-publish` plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html) a lot more flexible and easier to use to publish to maven repos.

Comment: The article you linked to, [links to another blog post](https://chris.banes.me/2013/08/27/pushing-aars-to-maven-central/), which says `maven-publish` supercedes the `maven` plugin for repo publishing.

Comment: @RaGe I know about `maven-publish` (and I did read the other article you linked) but haven't had any luck with it. In particular, I don't know how to configure it so as to let it use `wagon-git` and try to publish artifacts on Bitbucket instead of Maven Central or a different Maven remote repository.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Fails silently, turn on `--info`. Probably the biggest hurdle in debugging the problem. For some reason, the folks who wrote the wagon-git deployer decided to write out error messages at the info level. So gradle fails silently without showing you any error messages. This is one of the messages I got with `--info` turned on:

   ```
   [INFO] [git] fatal: 'git@bitbucket.org/foragerr/mvn-deploy-test.git' does not appear to be a git repository
   ```

This is apparently a fatal error, but as far as gradle is concerned, everything is fine and dandy. Once you start reading these error messages, we can make real progress!

2. git url: The git URL [as outlined here](http://synergian.github.io/wagon-git/usage.html), starts with `git:`. The wagon-git deployer is activated when the url starts with `git:`. It is possible to use a `https:` url, but maven plugin will use an internal deployer rather than wagon-git. To explicitly use wagon-git, the url has to start with `git:`

   ```
   repository(url: "git:releases://git@bitbucket.org:foragerr/mvn-bitbucket-deploy-test.git")
   ```

where
`releases` is branch
`foragerr` is bitbucket username
`mvn-bitbucket-deploy-test` is bitbucket repo

3. Authentication: wagon-git uses SSH to connect to bitbucket. You need to setup both git on the local end and bitbucket repo on the remote end to use SSH.

   - [Setting up SSH for git](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-ssh-for-git-728138079.html) (I recommend not using a passcode, less secure, but convenient for automated deployments)
4. All Set! deploy to your bitbucket repo using `gradle uploadArchives`. See [example repo here](https://bitbucket.org/foragerr/mvn-bitbucket-deploy-test/src/1805652fbc8882aee5035c3287a4af791dbb4759/net/foragerr/test/mvn-bitbucket-deploy-test/?at=releases).

Sample build.gradle:

```
    group 'net.foragerr.test'
    version '1.2-SNAPSHOT'

    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'maven'

    sourceCompatibility = 1.5

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://raw.github.com/synergian/wagon-git/releases"
        }
    }

    configurations {
        deployerJar
    }

    dependencies {
        testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
        deployerJar "ar.com.synergian:wagon-git:0.2.3"
    }

    uploadArchives {
        repositories.mavenDeployer {
            configuration = configurations.deployerJar;
            repository(url: "git:releases://git@bitbucket.org:foragerr/mvn-bitbucket-deploy-test.git")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the wonderfully detailed answer. Unfortunately, still nothing properly works on my side. Apart from Android Studio being unable to allow setting flags for anything other than build operations, and me being forced to use the command line to try and upload those artifacts, the `--info` flag shows nothing specific, and I just know that "Task has not declared any outputs" for `uploadArchives` when using a remote repository. Also, using a repository on my local filesystem does not create any metadata file similar to those I noticed on your Bitbucket repository.

Comment: Comment out both the config line and the bitbucket repo line when doing the local filesystem repo. Also, apparently wagon-git has a debug mode, try enabling `-Dwagon.git.debug=true`

Comment: I just realized something - by using a `https:` url instead of a `git:` url, I'm not invoking wagon-git at all, instead I'm actually using the maven plugin's built in deployer - which evidently works, but probably isn't what you're looking for. I'll take a look at this again today and update my answer.

Comment: So apparently if you use a `git:` url, wagon-git uses ssh to connect to bit bucket instead of username/password authentication. If you're on linux, this would be pretty straightforward, which is probably why the article you linked to does not even mention it. On windows, setting up SSH properly was arduous - I certainly learned a few things. I will update my answer shortly.

Comment: I cannot succed to deploy an android librairy to my private Bitbucket Repository even after reading this topic. I have a multi module project in Android Studio, each module is a aar library I want to share. can anyone could post an ENTIRE build.gradle example ?

Comment: check my answer bellow for a working solution using an app password.

Answer (score 8):

Here is all you need to do, you even need to use the git protocol (**this examples show how to use the HTTPS instead**):

1) create an app password for your app in Bitbucket

```
https://bitbucket.org/account/user/YOUR_USERNAME_HERE/app-passwords
```

2) inside *build.gradle*:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'

// artifact --> rootProject.name at settings.gradle <--
// DOWN HERE just add your artifact INFO
group = 'br.com.fora.temer'
version = '0.1-SNAPSHOT'
description = """Diretas Ja"""

dependencies {
    // your dependencies goes here, like this -->
    // compile group: 'br.gov.governo', name: 'golpista', version:'2.0'
}

apply from: 'uploadArchives.gradle' // --> deploy configuration
```

3) inside *uploadArchives.gradle* (you need to create it):

```
configurations {
    deployerJars
}

dependencies {
    deployerJars "ar.com.synergian:wagon-git:0.2.5" // plugin
}

uploadArchives {
    configuration = configurations.archives
    repositories.mavenDeployer {
        configuration = configurations.deployerJars
        repository(url: "git:releases://https://YOUR_USERNAME:YOUR_APP_PASSWORD@bitbucket.org/YOUR_COMPANY/repo-release.git")
        snapshotRepository(url: "git:snapshots://https://YOUR_USERNAME:YOUR_APP_PASSWORD@bitbucket.org/YOUR_COMPANY/repo-snapshot.git")
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://raw.github.com/synergian/wagon-git/releases"}
    }
}
```

To deploy use:

```
gradle uploadArchives
```

**TIP:** beware the order of the entries... if you change it, it will break everything.

Comment: BEWARE! When setting YOUR_USERNAME, use a DIFFERENT USER than the repository owner, otherwise it will NOT WORK... this cost me lots of hairs.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is old, but there isn't a lot of information on the topic, so I guess it is the right place to add some clues. I faced the same problems, there seemed to be no way to get it working. So there are some clues which might help:

1. As already been said, this whole ***maven plugin wagon*** thingy uses SSH to connect to repository (Bitbucket in my case). So you need to check a few things:

   - that Bitbuchet knows about your SSH key.go to your profile settings(**not repository settings!**) -> SSH keys and put there your **public** key received by keygen. There is instruction in the little 'insert key' window on Bitbucket to help you out.
   - that you have added your **private key** generated by keygen to your ssh agent (type **ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa** fot Linux and probably mac)
   - also add credentials to your repository element:

`repository(url: 'git:releases://git@bitbucket.org:gendalf/repo.git'){
       authentication(userName: "gendalf", password: "swordfish") }`

2. That plugin won't get confuzed about your output file. When I started to try uploading my library to the repository, I had ***flavors*** in it, so plugin didn't know which variant to select and selected nothing (apparently).

   - this stuff doesn't work with flavors as far as I know. So if you have flavors in the library which you are posting to private repository... consider getting rid of flavors. You probably don't need them anyway.
   - if you tried other publishing plugins before trying out **maven** (for example **maven-publish**), comment out all the script related to other stuff or delete it. My gradle was confused because of the additional scripts.
3. Consider trying out this https://jeroenmols.com/blog/2016/02/05/wagongit/ solution. It's what I used to finally publish, although it is pretty confusing about checking out from your just-created repository. Don't check out. Create the repository and publish right after that.

I hope this helps.